# How to include another table in JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

Below is my mysql query

```
SELECT 
    opensalesorder.so_number,
    items.VendorName,
    opensalesorder.item_number,
    items_custom_fields.FieldValue AS `Stock Item`,
    vendor_custom_fields.FieldValue AS `Paid Freight Allowance`,
    items.QuantityOnHand,
    items.ReorderPoint,
    items.MaxQty,
    SUM(opensalesorder.quantity_on_order),
    items.PurchaseCost,
    items.VendorName,
    items.VendorName,
    items.PurchaseCost,
    opensalesorder.status,
    items.ItemType
FROM
    vendor,
    `opensalesorder` 
inner join  items 
  on opensalesorder.item_number = items.ItemName
JOIN items_custom_fields 
  ON items_custom_fields.ItemName = items.ItemName
JOIN vendor_custom_fields 
  ON vendor_custom_fields.VName = vendor.VName
WHERE opensalesorder.item_number = items.ItemName 
        and items_custom_fields.FieldName ='Stock Item' 
        and vendor_custom_fields.FieldName ='Paid Freight Allowance' 
        and opensalesorder.status NOT LIKE 'on po'  
        AND opensalesorder.so_number NOT IN ('2','3') 
        AND items.VendorName NOT IN ('Access') 
        AND opensalesorder.item_number NOT IN ('018-0001')  
        group by opensalesorder.item_number
LIMIT 100
```

on executing this query I am getting error like

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'vendor.VName' in 'on clause'
```

But I have included the vendor table in FROM clause.
Is this right way to include a table in JOIN ?
So whats wrong is with this query ?

**EDIT:**

SHOW CREATE TABLE FOR opensalesorder

```
CREATE TABLE `opensalesorder` (
  `so_number` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `item_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `quantity_on_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity_to_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `editsequence` text NOT NULL,
  `TxnLineID` text NOT NULL,
  `TxnID` text NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` date NOT NULL,
  `shipDate` date NOT NULL,
  `customer` text NOT NULL,
  `itemclass` text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_mapping` (`so_number`,`item_number`),
  KEY `so_number` (`so_number`),
  KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE FOR items

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `ItemName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `VendorName` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QuantityOnHand` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QuantityOnSalesOrder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReorderPoint` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchaseCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `AverageCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SalesPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchaseDesc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SalesDesc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemType` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FreeCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubGroup` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateNewItem` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Notes` text,
  `MaxQty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QuantityOnPO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ItemName`),
  KEY `ItemName` (`ItemName`),
  KEY `VendorName` (`VendorName`)
)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE FOR vendor_custom_fields

```
CREATE TABLE `vendor_custom_fields` (
  `VName` text NOT NULL,
  `FieldName` text NOT NULL,
  `FieldValue` text NOT NULL,
  `FieldType` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VName`(120),`FieldName`(120)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `VName_index` (`VName`)
)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE FOR vendor

```
 CREATE TABLE `vendor` (
  `VName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Address1` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `AlternatePhone` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `AlternateContact` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `AccountNumber` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Balance` double NOT NULL,
  `RepEmail` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `FreightAllowance` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MinimumPOLimit` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Notes` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VName`)
)
```

Comment: Well, is there a `VName` column in your vendor table? On a side note, you've included `items.VendorName` in your result list twice.

Comment: Yes... There is VName in Vendor

Comment: @Perception Thrice. :)

Comment: Well This query is generated dynamically depending on select column combo box thats why it came thrice :)

Comment: Can you also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all the tables?

Comment: @DreamEater : I have added show create table for opensalesorder, items and vendor_custom_fields

Comment: And for `vendor` table?

Comment: @DreamEater : Added for vendor table now ...

Comment: Try changing the old-style cross join between `vendor` and `opensalesorder` into a explicit `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is mixing the implied join with the (unimplied) 'stated' joins. When I put 'vendor' in as a regular join the query was fine.

(I had to comment out references to 'items_custom_fields' as you didn't include the table definition)

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c21174/9).

Comment: items_custom_fields has same create table structure just change the VName with ItemName

Comment: Either way - that's not the issue here. Change the structure of the query (only slightly) and it works.